# Intersection and union of simply connected domain

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

I have some basics concept that, in $\mathbb{C}$, a "simply connected domain $D$" is a region in $\mathbb{C}$ with no holes. I am not sure whether it has various formal definition , but the one used in my complex analysis class looks very complicated. I barely understand what it means :

$\textbf{Definition}$ Let $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ be two continuous closed path in a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ parameterized by $I = [0,1]$;that is, $\gamma_i(0) = \gamma_i(1)$ for all $i = 0, 1.$ We say $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ are $\textbf{homotopic as closed paths on D}$ if there exists function $\delta : I \times I \rightarrow D$ such that

$1) \ \delta(t,0) = \gamma_0(t) \ \forall t \in I \ \ $    $2) \ \delta(t,1) = \gamma_1(t) \ \forall t \in I \ \ $     $3) \ \delta(0,u) = \delta(1,u) \ \forall u \in I.$

A continuous closed path is $\textbf{homotopic to a point}$ if it is homotopic to a constant path(as a closed path).

$\textbf{Definition}$ A region $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is called $\textbf{simply conected}$ if every continuous closed path in $D$ is homotopic to a point in $D$.

$\textbf{Problem :}$ 1) Let $D_1, D_2$ be simply connected plane domains whose intersection is nonempty and connected. Prove that their intersection and union are both simply connected.

2) Let $P, Q$ be smooth functions on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, Find necessary and sufficient condition for the form $P dz + Q d\bar{z}$ to be closed.

Comment: Any suggestion for solving problem ? Or some helpful notion about the definition ?

Comment: For a proof that the union is simply-connected, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158301/a-criterion-to-prove-that-a-topological-space-is-simple-connected/1159096#1159096

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler definition of simply connected for subsets of the plane. A set is simply in connected in $\Bbb C$ if, and only if its complement is connected.

Comment: Really ? It sounds more understandable, connected is the same as in general topology, right ? Anyway, my book does not provide this definition and I guess that I need to use the definition above to prove the problem. Can anyone suggest or explain something helpful ?

Comment: Yes, the usual definition of connectedness.

Comment: Any suggestion for the problem ? I am now trying to find the proof show the equivalence of the above definition of simply connected domain and the one use connectedness.

Comment: Its a little early for me

Comment: If and only if its complement in the *sphere* is connected, you mean.

Comment: No. I meant the complex plane. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: Take the complement of, say, $|\text{Re}(z)| \geq 1$, and use this as our domain. (This deletes two rays on the $x$-axis: one going to the right from $1$, one to the left from $-1$). Then this is a simply connected open set whose complement is disconnected. However, it's connected to $\infty$. (Also, if you consider $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$, this is complement connected in $\Bbb C$ but not in $S^2$.) Sorry about the delay - the software doesn't seem to have pinged me about your comment for some reason.

Comment: There did seem to be a delay in my comment being posted. I see what you mean. I wasn't thinking in terms of the exrended plane. Simple connectedness usually comes up in terms of  Cauchy's Integral Theorem. In this situation, we are looking at simple connectedness in just the plane.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1 a)** : showing that $D_1 \cup D_2$ is simply connected is a corollary from Van Kampen's theorem. But it can be proved with elementary arguments. In fact, if $\alpha$ is a loop in $D_1 \cup D_2$, we can take the connected components $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ of $\alpha \cap D_1$. These components exist because $D_1 \cap D_2$ is connected and hence arcwise connected (since open).

Because $D_1$ is simply connected, we can find an homotopy from $\alpha_i$ to $\tilde{\alpha_i}$ where $\tilde{\alpha_i}$ is a path with same endpoints as $\alpha_i$ and in $D_1 \cap D_2$.

Now, let $\beta$ be the loop obtained by removing each $\alpha_i$ by $\tilde{\alpha_i}$. $\beta$ is homotopic to $\alpha$ and $\beta \subset D_2$, and then homotopic to some constant loop.

**Problem 1 b)** You can use here the caracterisation of  Tim Raczkowski. Then, $(D_1 \cap D_2)^c = D_1^c \cup D_2^c$, and the union of two connected set with non-empty intersection is connected.

**Problem 2** : just think in $\mathbb R^2$ ( and think about Green's theorem too).

Comment: For problem 2,I have $$P dz + Q d\bar{z} = (P+Q) dx + (Pi - Qi)dy. $$ Since, if $\omega = P \ dx + Q \ dy$ is a $C^1$ function, then $\omega$ is closed on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ iff $P_y = Q_x$ on $D$. So if $\omega = P \ dz + Q d \bar{z}$, then $\omega$ is closed on $D$ iff $$P_x - i P_y = -Q_x - iQ_y$$ or $$P_z = -Q_{\bar{z}}$$ if $P_z = \frac{1}{2}(P_x - i P_y), Q_{\bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2} (Q_x + i Q_y)$ (it is just a notation, not partial diff respect to $z$ or $\bar{z}$. Is it correct ?

Comment: ???? Is my work okay ? Could anyone please check or comments ? If it is okay, then I can write down my work. Thank you in advanced and sorry for bothering you guys to much.

Comment: could you please review my solution ?